# Can't find cs 1003 syntax error, ',' expected

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown(RKey))
     {
         objNum = (Random.Range(0,6));
         if (objNum = 1)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 1);
         }
         if (objNum = 2)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 2);
         }
         if (objNum = 3)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 3);
         }
         if (objNum = 4)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 4);
         }
         if (objNum = 5)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 5);
         }
         if (objNum = 6)
         {
             Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 6);
         }

     }

 }
```

This is my code I have a lot of Syntax error's coming up. I'm doing this by watching a tutorial and I copied every code but it's not working. I'm a noob at Blender, sorry.

Comment: First of all i doubt that code does what you expect. Unless you truly want to test setting values of objnum. Second switch statements are way more efficient. And lastly. What is “ Roundcube ROLLING DICE 1” supposed to achieve? You probably meant quotes round it.

Comment: @BugFinder diagnosed the first problem, but was coy about the details.  Where you have `=` in the `if` statements, you need to have `==`.  `==` is the comparison operator.  `=` is assignment.  All except the first should be `else if`.  Unless you have dozens of cases, an `if/else if` string is just as efficient as a `switch` (the machine code is identivcal).

Comment: Also remember `Random.Range(0,6)` will return a value between 0 and 6.  You're not handling 0.  And when you have repeated code like this,  there's almost always a better way.  In this case, create an array of 6 entries with your string, and use the random value as a lookup in that array.  No more if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the advice of BugFinder and Tim Roberts.

Gave you some examples

1. your Animator.Play need a string and it looks like this "Text in a string"

   ```
    // Before 
    Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(Roundcube ROLLING DICE 6);

    // After    
    Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 6");
   ```
2. your if statements need to be == not =.

   ```
    // Before 
    if (objNum = 1)

    // After    
    if (objNum == 1)
   ```
3. Random.Range(NumberA,NumberB) is a random range from NumberA to NumberB -1.
   so Random.Range(0,6) is 0 to 5.
   so you want Random.Range(1,7) to get 1 to 6.

   ```
    // Before 
    objNum = (Random.Range(0,6));

    // After    
    objNum = (Random.Range(1,7));
   ```

Use a switch as Tim Roberts say.
or you can simply change the number in the string.

```
void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetButtonDown(RKey))
        {
            objNum = (Random.Range(1, 7));
            Animator animator = Roundcube.GetComponent<Animator>();

            switch (objNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 3");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 4");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 5");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    animator.Play("Roundcube ROLLING DICE 6");
                    break;
                default:
            }

            // or

            animator.Play($"Roundcube ROLLING DICE {objNum}");
        }
    }
```